# C++ Code that manipulates CSV file outputs correctly via Sublime Text Command Palette...but not in Terminal

Tags: c++, csv, terminal, sublimetext3, fstream

For my latest lab I was given a fairly basic assignment - take a CSV file with population data and output various details, like the country with the largest population. For the sake of brevity, I've included a truncated version of my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

  struct Country {
    string name;
    double pop1950;
    double pop1970;
    double pop1990;
    double pop2010;
    double pop2015;
  };

  struct World {
    int numCountries;
    Country countries[229]; // plugged this value with the number of countries from the CSV file. 
  } myWorld;

  int main()
  {
     ifstream csvStream; 
     csvStream.open ("population.csv");

        double vpop1950;
        double vpop1970;
        double vpop1990;
        double vpop2010;
        double vpop2015;
        string conName;

        int counter = 0; 


       while (csvStream >> vpop1950 >> vpop1970 >> vpop1990 >> vpop2010 >> vpop2015) 
       {
        getline(csvStream, conName);
        // instantiate a country structure per line. 

        myWorld.countries[counter].name = conName; 
        myWorld.countries[counter].pop1950 = vpop1950; 
        myWorld.countries[counter].pop1970 = vpop1970;
        myWorld.countries[counter].pop1990 = vpop1990; 
        myWorld.countries[counter].pop2010 = vpop2010;
        myWorld.countries[counter].pop2015 = vpop2015; 
        counter++;

        // cout << conName << endl; 
       }

       // For task 2, where are going to get the top 3 countries. Let's start with the top country, and repeat the loop below 2 more times.

       // Figure out the biggest population.
       double placeVal = myWorld.countries[0].pop2015; // use this to compare and store the top 100 
       string topCon = " ";

       for (int i = 0; i < 229; i++)
       {
        if (placeVal < myWorld.countries[i].pop2015)
        {
            placeVal = myWorld.countries[i].pop2015;
            topCon = myWorld.countries[i].name;
        }
       }

       cout << "The largest country is" << topCon << " which had " << placeVal * 1000 << " people in 2015." << endl; // Multiplied by 1000 as per lab instructions. 

     return 0;

     csvStream.close();

  }
```

When I type Command+Shift+B in sublime text and have the file compile and execute, I get this output:

```
The largest country is China
 which had 1.37605e+09 people in 2015.
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Execute that same executable in terminal, and I get the following (on both mac and ubuntu):

```
The largest country is  which had 0 people in 2015.
```

My actual code is a fair bit longer, and I perform various other calculations in that original version of my program, but the same bug persists - the output shows in sublime text but not in the actual terminal. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked if the data from the CSV file is read in correctly when running from the Terminal?

Comment: Andy, thank you for replying...would you mind elaborating a bit? I'm not sure how I would confirm that the data is being read in correctly.

Comment: @ChristT You could print out some of the variables from within the while loop. Your program assumes that `population.csv` is in the current working directory. If that isn't the case when running your program from the terminal, then it won't read in the data from the file.

Comment: @Andy, so I think you're on to something....I do have the csv file in the same directory as the directory I execute my programs in, but I tried having a message sent to cout every time my program read a line from the .csv file...it outputs the message in sublime text, but not in the terminal. So obviously something is happening where the filestream is not stuffing data into variables like it should.

Comment: when you execute the program, is the current directory in terminal in that same directory? Even if the file is in the same directory as the program (such as `~/src/my_program`) if the current directory in terminal is different (such as just your home directory) then the program's current directory will be your home directory, not `~/src/my_program`.

Comment: Andy, Thank you - now I'm seeing the output! I didn't realize executing a file in a directory was not the same as actively being in that directory and reading files within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program assumes that `population.csv` is in the current working directory. If the current directory does not contain that file, then that file won't be able to be read in.

SublimeText most likely sets the current directory when executing your program to the directory where that program is located.

When running commands from a terminal, the executed program inherits the current directory from the terminal. For example, if your program is in `~/src/my_program`, but the current directory in the terminal is your home directory, then the current directory for your program will be your home directory, not `~/src/my_program`.

If you change the current directory in the terminal to the directory where your program is located, then the file should be read in correctly.